# Php sending commands to a background process

Tags: php, exec, pipe

I am writing a web-service. The PHP processor should handover the processing to an executable file located on the server.

On arrival of a request , the PHP should run the executable & take the output from the executable back & process it further in PHP , while the executable continues to run in the background. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The background process is a PHP script?

Comment: Please give more information or this post will be unsalvagable and be closed due to little reusability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a webservice, which can run calculations in background and used files to communicate.

- Request from client
- create job file
- start background php cli which runs job file
- if the job process is done, it writes it's result to a result file
- when the client requests the result from a job, the server process reads it from the result file